# Where does Adobe XD store plugins when installed from the store (on mac)?

Tags: macos, plugins, adobe, adobe-xd

I am trying to create an Adobe XD plugin which will export artboards into HTML and CSS, but I also need to add some extra functionality before exporting.

I wanted to use the code from the Web Export plugin and add some of my own functionality to it.
So I want to know where the XD plugins are stored. They Do not seem to be available in the Developer directory.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that they are stored at (on MAC)

```
/Users/<USERNAME>/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe XD/plugins
```